# Retrieve values from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am retrieving values from JSON and want to compare that. but I am getting Index Out of Range Exception on:

```
string email = contactdata.data[0].email[i].value;
```

Code:

```
 int length = contactdata.data.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
            {
                string email = contactdata.data[0].email[i].value;
                    if (contactemail == email)
                {
                    counter++;
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

JSON Class:

```
  public class Rootobject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public Additional_Data additional_data { get; set; }         
    }

    public class Additional_Data
    {
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pagination
    {
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public bool more_items_in_collection { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public int id { get; set; }             
        public Email[] email { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public bool primary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the for loop. You're getting the length of contactdata.data, but you're using it to access contactdata.data.email. You can't be sure there even IS an email for that particular data! Try using a nested for loop, get the length of contactdata.data.email and access email in the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

change the line

```
int length = contactdata.data.Length;
```

to

```
int length = contactdata.data[0].email.Length;
```

and change the condition in the for loop from `i <= length` to `i < length`.

Comment: I am using this but I am getting length = 1 but there are total 18 records.

Comment: If I use length = contactdata.data[0].email.Length ; then It will compare with first one only.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

index start alwais from 0

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration variable is on the `contactdata.data`not on email, thus your `i` variable is on these indexes.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, using a nested for loop over data and ALSO over email will ensure you actually have an email you can look at!

The index out of range error means that you're trying to access an item in an array that doesn't exist.

I did not test the following code, but I used really explicit variable names in the loop to show you what I'm trying to count, and how I can only access something in an array if I know that it actually exists:

```
//first get the length of data
var dataLength = contactdata.data.Length;
//now loop through it
for (var dataCounter = 0; dataCounter < dataLength; dataCounter++){
  //next get the length of email - is there even an email available?
  var emailLength = contactdata.data[dataCounter].email.Length;
  for (var emailCounter = 0; emailCounter < emailLength; emailCounter ++){
    //now you can access the email and work with it.
     if (contactemail == contactdata.data[dataCounter].email[emailCounter]){
       // here do your code
     }
  }
}
```